# javascript dynamic table filling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I have multiple arrays lets say:

```js
var animals = ["cow","horse","rabbit","elephant","donkey","monkey","zebra"];
var food = ["apple","banana","pear","melon","grape","peach","pineapple"];
```

I want to put this in 4-column table dynamically. if click on animals picture the animals array would fill the table, if food, then food array would fill the table.

So, lets say I have

```
<table class="myTable"></table>
```

Then need javascript

```js
import $ from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/jquery@3.6.1";
var animals = ["cow","horse","rabbit","elephant","donkey","monkey","zebra"];
var food = ["apple","banana","pear","melon","grape","peach","pineapple"];
    
var $table = $('.myTable');
for (var i = 0; i < food.length; i++){
    var $aSingleContent = '<tr><td>'+food[i]+'</td></tr>';
    $table.append($aSingleContent);
}
```

This would display all food items in 1 column. Now I need to divide this by 4 - because 4 columns in a row

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve]. It may also help to describe what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 1):

because of `<tr>` in line `var $aSingleContent = '<tr><td>'+food[i]+'</td></tr>';` makes your javascript create a new row for every element in array. we need to keep count the amount of data that had filled a row. if a row has 4 columns `columnCount === 4`, then we create a new row.

```js
const food = ["apple","banana","pear","melon","grape","peach","pineapple"];
    
const $table = $('.myTable');
let $aSingleContent = "<tr>", columnCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < food.length; i++){
    if(columnCount === 4) {
        columnCount = 0;
        $aSingleContent += '</tr><tr>';
    }
    $aSingleContent += '<td>'+food[i]+'</td>';
    columnCount++;
}
$aSingleContent += "</tr>"
$table.append($aSingleContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myTable" border></table>
```

Comment: Nice.  You can skip columnCount if you use `if(i > 0 && i % 4 === 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var animals = ["cow","horse","rabbit","elephant","donkey","monkey","zebra"];
    var food = ["apple","banana","pear","melon","grape","peach","pineapple"];
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var i = 0, r = 0;
    while(i < animals.length) {
      var row = table.insertRow(r);
      for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
        var cell = row.insertCell(c);
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(animals[i] ? animals[i] : ''));
        i++;
      }
      r++;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
</table>
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have `food` array more than you provide you can use this one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-w8CvhFs7iHNVUtnSP0YKEg00p9Ih13rlL9zGqvLdePA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table class="myTable" border="1">
</table>

<script>
 
var animals = ["cow","horse","rabbit","elephant","donkey","monkey","zebra"];
var food = ["apple","banana","pear","melon","grape","peach","pineapple", "a","b","c","d"];


var $table = $('.myTable');
    
    var $aSingleContent = '';
    var to = 0;
    var from = 3;
    for (var i = 0; i < food.length; i++){
 
      if (i==to)
      { $aSingleContent += '<tr>'; }
      $aSingleContent += '<td>'+food[i]+'</td>';
      if (i==from)
      { 
        $aSingleContent += '</tr>'; 
        to = to + 4;
        from = from + 4;
      }  
    }
    
    $table.append($aSingleContent);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```